# How to delete a uploaded version, and add a new version, in the New iTunes connect

Tags: ios, build, upload, version, app-store-connect

I have a app, with 1.6.0 version ready for sale, and 1.6.1 version rejected.

Now i want to delete 1.6.1 version, and upload a new version. how to ?

---

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot 'delete' the rejected version, but can edit and change the version number.

Goto 'General App Information' part of 'Version Information' page of the previous version (1.6.1), change Version from 1.6.1 to 2.0.0.

Answer (score 1):

You do not delete it, just change the version number, scroll down to where the version number is listed and change it to 2.0.0

[image]

Comment: tks, it's very useful. i have to choose the earlier answer, you both are right.